# Allow close votes on questions I've already flagged

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close

Working on the review queue after I was granted the privilege, I don't see why I shouldn't be able to cast a close vote on a question I've flagged previously.

[image]

Please allow me to cast a close vote if I've flagged the answer previously.

Or count the flags as close votes? If so, then please don't show the questions in the review queue.

Comment: If memory serves, flagging for closure automatically converts to a close vote anyway (when the flag is approved).  Why are you flagging for closure when you have the ability to vote to close?